# How to achieve an smooth height transition when adding new elements to a Panel in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, css-transitions, uibinder, gwtp

I have a FocusPanel that when gets clicked adds new Elements/Widgets to itself making its height increase. Note, that there is no explicit change of height in the css of the FocusPanel, the height just increases as the result of adding new elements inside the panel

I would like that increase in height to occur through a smooth transition but I am not sure how to achieve it.

I tried applying css `transition: height 2s;` to the FocusPanel and also to all the other Elements/Widgets that I add to it. But it does not seem to work, there is no transition at all. I assume it is because the height does not increase as a result of me changing the css property but rather by just adding more elements to a container.

What is the right way to achieve a smooth transition of height when adding new elements programatically to a Panel? Thanks!

PS. A good example of what I would like to achieve is the way twitter handles the transition of the panel height when one clicks on a twit.

Comment: May this helps you http://blog-demo.appspot.com/#animation

Comment: I am afraid you would need to controll the height programatically in your application. So whenever you add or remove an element from your panel, you calculate new height and animate the size change. In order to achieve animation you can use several frameworks: GQuery, GWT Animation or HTML transitions.

Comment: and BTW you can check how twitter does it. Just open FireBug (or other tool for web devs) and see what happens with parameters of twitter panel. Is the height changing? or do they have other trick to do that?

Answer (score 2):

CSS animations only work if you set the height to fixed values.

A way is to create your own implementation of panel, and override the add method, so as it takes care of computing height and setting it before and after animation time.

As @fascynacja points in its comment, I would go with [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to do that, because of different reasons, but main one is that it is a lightweight library developed in gwt which allows you doing a lot of things with few code lines.

Here you have an example of a panel doing what you want using gquery animations.

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
[...]

// Create your own implementation of a panel
public static class MyFlowPanel extends FlowPanel {

  // The GQuery object for this panel
  GQuery $this = $(this);

  // Override the add method so as each time it is called, we run an animation
  // You can do the same with the remove method.
  @Override
  public void add(Widget w) {
    // Compute the actual height
    int hInitial = $this.height();
    // Set height to auto before adding the new child.
    $this.height("auto");
    // Add the new widget to panel
    super.add(w);
    // Compute the new height
    int hFinal = $this.height();

    // Use Gquery to .animate the panel from the old to the new height
    // You could replace this with css3 transitions
    $this.height(hInitial)
         .stop(true)
         .animate("height: " + hFinal, 2000);
  };
};

public void onModuleLoad() {
  // Create your panel, and use it as usual in GWT
  final FlowPanel myFlowPanel = new MyFlowPanel();
  RootPanel.get().add(myFlowPanel);
  // Set some css properties to your panel. You could set these in your style-sheet.
  $(myFlowPanel).css($$("border: 1px solid grey; border-radius: 8px; background: #F5FFFA; width: 500px; padding: 8px"));

  // Add 10 labels to the panel in periodes of 1000 ms
  Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedPeriod(new RepeatingCommand() {
    int c = 10;
    public boolean execute() {
      if (c-- > 0) {
        myFlowPanel.add(new Label(c + " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."));
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks tocayo. I understand the basis of your explanation. Overriding the add method looks like a neat solution to me. I'll try it later in the week. I will also consider using GQuery. BTW, don't you think it is less CPU efficient to use GWT/GQuery animations than CSS's transitions?

Comment: sure, it less efficient but depends where your bottle-neck is. If you want animate something when you are processing data, do not, because animation wont be fluid. But normally to do something like twitter does it does not matter.

Comment: understood, thanks. Another follow-up comment about your suggestion of using gquery. If have understood correctly gquery provides two main advantages -besides the built-in fancy effects-: 1)less lines of code than when using plain GWT. 2)I don't need to hold instances of my widgets to access them. This, I suppose, reduces the memory footprint of the client? (although I have no idea how GWT translates instances to JS... maybe it uses its own css selector framework?). Am I missing something else?